# Git clone is not fetching the latest changes from git repository

Tags: git

I am using git repository. I did some changes to a file and committed the changes. 
I created a fresh view (git clone)  and I wont see the changes I committed. When I do "git pull", I will start seeing my changes. Any reasons? How to get the changes on the first clone itself? Is this related to any problem during my first commit? Please reply.

Comment: Do you `pull` from the same place that you `clone` from? Did you maybe forget to push your commit?

Comment: Are you realy using git clone and not git fetch or git remote update?

Comment: Also
Did commited changes to master in first repo? 
Did git clone really happened after commit?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have pushed your changes to a different branch on the same repository. In that case, you can checkout the remote branch on your local copy. Use **git branch -a** to inspect all remote branches and checkout them using the **git checkout** command